# Make GPG encrypted file look like binary executable

Tags: encryption, gpg

I have a weird ask.
I have a tar achive, `archive.tar.gz`, filled with plaintext files. That archive is then gpg encrypted into `archive.tgz.gpg`. In total, `archive.tgz.gpg` is < 100KB.

Now, I want to make `archive.tgz.gpg` look like a linux binary, and have it be un-obfuscated using mostly unix standard utilities. I'm aware that it's (very likely) not going to *work* as a binary executable, and that's ok. But at a cursory glance, it should roughly appear as a corrupted binary executable.

The furthest I've gotten is trying to modify the header using `cat` and `dd` so that `file` doesn't correctly return the file type, but I haven't gotten very far in finding much information about doing this online.

If someone would be able to help point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can totally embed the payload into a working executable.

```
echo "I am your encrypted message." > message.txt
gpg2 --symmetric message.txt
ld -r -b binary -o message.o message.txt.gpg
gcc -o unsuspicious unsuspicious.c message.o
```

With `unsuspicious.c` containing any program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hi. I am a totally unsuspicious executable.\n");
}
```

With this technique, the payload will end up in the .data section of the binary. To retrieve it, extract the entire data section:

```
objcopy --dump-section .data=data.bin unsuspicious
```

Some other data is preceeding my 104 bytes of payload. I used `nm unsuspicious` to determine the exact difference between `__data_start` and `_binary_message_txt_gpg_start`, in my case 16 bytes. Knowing this, I can retrieve the payload:

```
dd if=data.bin skip=16 bs=1 count=104 of=message.txt.gpg
```

Whether this is a valid implementation for your goal depends on whether you consider `nm`, `objcopy` and `dd` "standard utilities". Of course, you can always add some logic to the program itself so it just prints the payload if asked nicely.

Answer (score 3):

what's the point? Just make an executable with the file embedded.

```bsh
ld --format=binary archive.tgz.gpg executable_file
```

will give you something that is actually an ELF executable. It will not run (there's no `_start` symbol that could be executed).

If you want that, write a C/C++/… program with a `main` function, e.g main.c `int main(){}`, then build your data-containing object file using `ld --relocatable --format=binary archive.tgz.gpg mixin.o` and finally build together with your program, `gcc main.c mixin.o -o main`.

You can get the data back out rather trivially, and you can get the data section out using the rather standard binutils tools `readelf` or `objcopy`. Even easier, you could have the program extract the contents to a file only if specific conditions are met. (e.g. check whether a certain string is in `environ`)

Now, no expert will be fooled by that – your embedded archive has high *empirical entropy*, and binary analysis tools like `radare2` will detect that, no matter what you do to obfuscate.

What you can do is artificially inflate the size of the encrypted archive by e.g. mapping each byte of the ciphertext to a different member of a set of typical machine code excerpts (not necessarily even constant-length, but prefix-free) from real-world C programs. But then, you'd have to de-map that – and that would require your dictionary and would become rather annoying to do just with standard tools.